# How do the following videos work

Tags: daw

[This video](https://youtu.be/cSAp9sBzPbc) is a version of Rick Astley's Never gonna give you up,

> except all notes are C.

What does one change in the original compositions to *make all notes in a song to be of the same pitch*? Do they take relative notes, because I've only heard of relative keys, Eg: A minor being relative to C major.

And if all the notes are the same, wouldn't the song pretty much be a continuous and monotonous pitch? How do such microtonal variations (as seen in the video) arise?

Comment: I downvoted because I can't see how this question is useful here. But I have answered it anyway because the answers are pretty clear.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. To make all the notes in a composition be C, you just take every single note, keep all the properties of the note except the pitch and write it as a C. But in the video it is just shifted with some kind of software...

Comment: What other properties does a note have apart from its pitch?

Comment: @noorav instrument it is played on (timbre), duration, volume, attack, decay, vibrato, sustain, other effects like distortion, reverb, etc.

Comment: *Rick*, not “Nick”

Comment: The list of note properties that I've seen most often is fourfold: pitch, loudness, timbre, and duration/timing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's important to note that not ALL of the notes are C. They have stabilized the bass and vocals on one pitch. The accompanying instruments are shifted as well, but not to C - they keep their relative position to the original notes.

You can hear the synths and strings hitting a variety of notes other than C.

Comment: Maybe I couldn't bear to listen to enough of it to hear this, but it sounded to me like it was all at C. But it would make sense if they just shifted the everything so all the vocal melody notes were C and then the other chords are changed relative to that.

Comment: It's especially noticeable if you listen to the strings on the chorus.

Answer (score 1):

They just used pitch shifting software to literally make every pitch a C.

In terms of "wouldn't the song pretty much be a continuous and monotonous pitch?", I'm not sure what *you're* hearing, but it **is** a continuous and monotonous pitch.

> How do such microtonal variations (as seen [sic] in the video) arise?

The pitch shifting software requires a short moment of music to detect the original pitch before it can shift it. So you're hearing maybe 1/10 of a second of the original pitch before it is quickly shifted to C. If you listen to his singing, you can hear how the pitch detection is much faster and all his vocal notes are just C.

Comment: Are you thinking they used something like melodyne?

Comment: @topomorto Probably.

Comment: It may be worth explaining how melodyne could be used to do this kind of thing - it's "not your father's" pitch shifter!